# Pergunta não foi para a fila de análise

Tags: bug, suporte, status-intencional

Eu fui na fila de análise e não havia nenhum item, poucos segundos depois vi [essa questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/30366/recalculate-numbers-in-array-after-removing-or-inserting?noredirect=1) que possuía quatro votos para ser encerrada e fiz o último voto o qual encerrou a mesma.

Se ver no histórico da fila de [votos para fechar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/close/history) verá que a mesma não se encontra por lá. Isso é um bug? Ou qual o motivo para tal comportamento?

Comment: Não sei se é o caso, mas pelo que eu observo do funcionamento do site existe um tempo para que o primeiro voto para fechar faça com que a pergunta vá para a fila de análises, acho que algo em torno de 20 minutos. É possível que você tenha visto a pergunta antes desse prazo para ela aparecer na fila, mas não tenho como ter certeza.

Comment: O mesmo acontece para a fila de primeiras publicações, às vezes a pergunta só entra na fila depois de editada, votada e algumas vezes respondida. Acredito que seja como o @Math disse, por causa de um delay

Comment: Em tempo real não é. Definitivamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fila de análise é atualizada a cada 15 minutos, então esse é o tempo que um post pode ficar sem ir pra fila mesmo com 4 votos dados. Em algumas circunstâncias mais obscuras, pode até ultrapassar os 15 minutos até que ele apareça na fila.

O seu voto foi dado com exatos 15 min de diferença pro primeiro, então a pergunta não foi pra fila.